# Strapi/Stripe: Update 'Sold' Field After Successful Purchase

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, e-commerce, strapi

I have been scratching my head on this one.
I am beginner with Strapi and Stripe and trying to make e-commerce site for practise.
How to set "sold" boolean to "true" after successful purchase? (in order to hide the paid products, since they are unique items)

I don't get errors in console, but bash gives me:

"Updating sold status for product ID: *Correct product ID*
Error updating sold boolean: Error: Model product not found"

But there indeed is "product" model.

this is the order controller:

```
"use strict";
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::order.order", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async create(ctx) {
    const { products } = ctx.request.body; 
    try {
      const lineItems = await Promise.all(
        products.map(async (product) => {
          const item = await strapi
            .service("api::product.product")
            .findOne(product.id);

          return {
            price_data: {
              currency: "usd",
              product_data: {
                name: item.title,
              },
              unit_amount: Math.round(item.price * 100),
            },
            quantity: 1,
          };
        })
      );

      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        shipping_address_collection: { allowed_countries: ["US"] },
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        mode: "payment",
        success_url: process.env.CLIENT_URL + "?success=true",
        cancel_url: process.env.CLIENT_URL + "?success=false",
        line_items: lineItems,
      });

      // Update the sold boolean to true for the purchased items
      const updateSoldStatus = async (productId) => {
        try {
          await strapi
            .query("product")
            .update({ id: productId }, { sold: true });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error updating sold boolean:", error);
        }
      };

      // Update the sold status for each purchased product
      for (const product of products) {
        console.log(`Updating sold status for product ID: ${product.id}`);
        await updateSoldStatus(product.id);
      }

      await strapi
        .service("api::order.order")
        .create({ data: { products, stripeId: session.id } });

      return { stripeSession: session };
    } catch (error) {
      ctx.response.status = 500;
      return { error };
    }
  },
}));
```

Attempted to use strapi.models.product